# Las vegas method?

Tags: monte-carlo, american

In one of his winning paper, backward induction for future values, A. Antonov, quant of the year 2016, refer to the American Monte-Carlo method as the Las Vegas method. Is this name used appart from him ?

Comment: Antonov works at Numerix, so this company is kinda pushing this terminology: [Press release](http://www.numerix.com/Press-Detail/r/PRESS_RELEASES-2718).

Comment: ok is this name used appart from him and numerix ?